# Send data to server from android device when app gets in background

Tags: android, service, background, android-asynctask, android-activity

Currently i can only send the data to the server when my app (activity) is in foreground. This happens at least in 4.1.3 because the android SO pauses the app or stops it.

I need to send data all the time even if the activity is in background.

What is the best way of achieving this. Asynctask is not a good answer because i want to send data periodically. Not once. I already use asynctasks as a way to send the data to the server what i need is something that runs together with the activity but doesn't get stopped by the SO.

EDIT:

I got this error using the below code.

```
04-03 13:55:28.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver main.inSituApp.BootCompletedIntentReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.inSituApp.BootCompletedIntentReceiver
```

Can anyone tell me what that error means? i dont have a class with that receiver but i though if i register it in the manifest i wouldn't need it.

Comment: Use a service: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Use intent service or service ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `services` and `AlarmManager` to do so. Simply register your application in services and call `alarmMangaer.setRepeat()` method to start your code of serverside or any other operation you want to do in `onStart()` method of services

```
public class MyService extends Service{
  Calendar cur_cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
            0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cur_cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            60 * 1000*3, pintent);
}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
          // your code for background process
  }
}
```

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<service
        android:name="com.yourpackage.MyService"
        android:enabled="true" />
  <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Edit:**
BootCompletedIntentReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i understood correctly what happenned is that the alarm manager will execute the service every 60*100*3 miliseconds?

Comment: Yes it will call your application in every 3 minutes.

Comment: Btw, the Calendar import is which?

Comment: And here is the receiver you declare in the android manifest?

Comment: Calender is from `java.util.Calendar` Yes receiver is to start our app in background again if user reboot device or app force stop. So receiver will restart the app services.

Comment: I had a error with that broadcastreceiver stuff. Can you pls check my edit?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal how could i stop this when i don't want to send any data from background service. I tried stop service from activity. Its doesn't help out. Still its running.

Comment: @Rameshababu you can stop sending data according to your logic of not sending to server. If you want to stop service then you can stop service by `mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, MyBackgroundService.class))`

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal so if i stop the service will cancel the alarm or what?

Comment: It will stop the service, alarm will again trigger as per duration mentioned.